# Stuck on a geometry proof

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram, $EF$ is a line segment dividing the sides $BC$ and $DA$ so that $DE$ is equal to $BF$.

[image]

Show that $|\triangle AEP| + |\triangle BFQ| = |\triangle PQK|$.
I tried redrawing the problem so the parallelogram is in a circumcircle, but nothing good came from that.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation?  Does $|\triangle ABC|$ mean the area of the triangle?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sorry! yes, it means the area!

Comment: Note that area of $\triangle ABK$ = area of  trapezoid $ABFE$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ area of parallelogram $ABCD$.

Comment: You can't put a general parallelogram into a circumcircle.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite trivial; if $DE = BF$, then $EF$ passes through the center of the parallelogram, hence quadrilateral $EFBA \cong FEDC$ each with area equal to half the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$.  But $\triangle AKB$ is also half the area of the parallelogram $ABCD$. So $$|\triangle AEP| + |\triangle BFQ| + |APQB| = |EFBA| = |\triangle AKB| = |\triangle PQK| + |APQB|.$$

Answer (score 2):

After George Brown's comment, we know that $|AEFB|=|AKB|=\frac{1}{2}|ABCD|$. Therefore
$$
|AEP| + |APQB|+|BFQ|=|AEFB|=|AKB|=|APQB|+|PQK|.
$$
that is, after removing $|APQB|$ from both sides,
$$
|AEP| +|BFQ|=|PQK|.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!